What's the proper way to calculate neap low tide and high tide tide-raising forces?
My coursemates (and maybe, through them, my professor) insist that to calculate the neap low-tide tide-raising forces, I should take $F=\frac{GMa}{d^3}$ for a point on the earth $90°$ from the nearest surface point (call this point $B$, this formula arises from an approximation of the general form dropping high powers of small terms when a<<d) and $F=\frac{2GMa}{d^3}$ for the nearest surface point (call this point $A$, also an approximation for when a<<d). In these formulae, $a$ is the radius of the Earth, $d$ is the distance to the tide-raising celestial body, and $M$ is the mass of that body. Then I should take $F_{a,\text{moon}} - F_{b,\text{sun}}$ for the neap high and $F_{a,\text{sun}} - F_{b,\text{moon}}$ for the neap low. Since in a neap tide, the Sun is $90°$ from the Moon and the forces are perpendicular, it's not apparent to me why the Sun should play any role in the neap high tide or the Moon play any role in the neap low tide. My proposed method would be to use the general, unapproximated force equation
$$F=\frac{Gm}{(d-a)^2}-\frac{Gm}{d^2}$$
for the Moon only for the neap high tide, and the same equation for the sun only for the neap low tide. Can anyone weigh in, or help explain why I'm wrong? There are a few questions I've seen here that are pretty close to this, but they seem to steer away from calculation of the actual tide-raising forces so I don't think this is a duplicate, but apologies if it is! Professor in this instance isn't terribly responsive, and I don't have any in-person interaction with them.
